# how to set password to pdf file while exporting from crystal report in vb.net programatically?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have written a code which creates a pdf file exporting from Crystal Reports in VB.NET 2005.
All the code is working fine and also PDF files are created ok, but I want to set a password to that PDF file programatically.
Is there any solution?

Below is my code to create PDF files while exporting from Crystal Reports

```
Dim CrExportOptions As ExportOptions
Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New DiskFileDestinationOptions()
Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()

CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "D:\PDFFiles\" & fileName

CrFormatTypeOptions.FirstPageNumber = 1 ' Start Page in the Report

CrFormatTypeOptions.LastPageNumber = 10 ' End Page in the Report

CrFormatTypeOptions.UsePageRange = True


CrExportOptions = CrReport.ExportOptions

With CrExportOptions

    .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
    .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat

    .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions

    .FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions

End With
CrReport.Export()
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Crystal Reports can export to PDF format but can't put any password protection on the resulting file (see one of many similar posts [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1311474)). There are third party tools that you can use to protect the resulting PDFs, but you can't do it during the export.
There is one post I found that mentions a successful export with password protection, but after unsuccessfully trying to navigate the mentioned site I gave up. Check it out for yourself [here](http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/vb-crystalreports-l/how-to-set-the-password-for-pdf-file-which-is-exporting-by-crystal-report-using-vb6-3244566) and maybe you have more luck.

Chris

Comment: ok as crystal report cant set password while exporting but can we set password after creation of file on hard disk.

Comment: If you do a search, you will find third party tools like this one: http://pdfsharp.com/

Comment: heres a [link](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=36&Itemid=47) of that shows how to set password using pdfsharp

Answer (score 2):

For people who are still searching for a solution, I have found a way to do it with the help of `PdfSharp`. You can add pdfsharp to your project using **Nuget Package Manager**. Then just add the following code -

```
System.IO.Stream st = CrReport.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(st);

PdfSecuritySettings securitySettings = document.SecuritySettings;

// Setting one of the passwords automatically sets the security level to 
// PdfDocumentSecurityLevel.Encrypted128Bit.
securitySettings.UserPassword = "user";
securitySettings.OwnerPassword = "owner";

// Don´t use 40 bit encryption unless needed for compatibility reasons
//securitySettings.DocumentSecurityLevel = PdfDocumentSecurityLevel.Encrypted40Bit;

// Restrict some rights.            
securitySettings.PermitAccessibilityExtractContent = false;
securitySettings.PermitAnnotations = false;
securitySettings.PermitAssembleDocument = false;
securitySettings.PermitExtractContent = false;
securitySettings.PermitFormsFill = true;
securitySettings.PermitFullQualityPrint = false;
securitySettings.PermitModifyDocument = true;
securitySettings.PermitPrint = false;

// Save the document...
document.Save(filename);
```